# Getting some dihedral angles in R

Tags: r

```
For this question:
“Getting all dihedral angles in Pymol”
```

- I found following  answer to separate the dihedral angles of a
  protein from the stackoverflow site

  library(bio3d)

  ```
   #returns the file path of the current working directory.
   getwd()   

   #sets the working directory to where you want.
   setwd("home/R/Rscripts") 


   #fetches the pdb file from the protein data bank and saves to dataframe 'pb'
   pb <- read.pdb("insert PDB ID")  
   #trim to protein only
   pb.prot <- trim.pdb(pb, "protein")

   #calculates the torsion angles of the protein and save to dataframe 'tor'
   tor <- torsion.pdb(pb.prot) 

   #to get the number of rows and columns of 'tor'
   dim(tor$tbl) 

   #identify each row by their chain, residue ID and residue Number obtained from your PDB entry
   res_label <- paste(pb.prot$atom$chain[pb.prot$calpha], pb.prot$atom$resid[pb.prot$calpha], pb.prot$atom$resno[pb.prot$calpha], sep="-") 

   rownames(tor$tbl) <- res_label

   #creates a table of the torsion angle
   torsion <- tor$tbl  
   #For example, to look at the angles for VAL, residue 223 from chain A
   tor$tbl["A-GLY-65",]
   #writes out the table to a file

        phi                      psi            chi1       chi2      chi3     chi4       chi5              
   -63.07696       -44.08316        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
  ```
- How do I change this code if I want to separate the angles of several
  rows?
  For example, the angles of rows

  ```
   A-PHE-123
    A-GLY-124  
   A-ALA-125  
   A-ASP-126  
   A-ALA-127  
   A-GLN-128
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
**#install bio3d library and call**

library(bio3d)

**#returns the file path of the current working directory.**

 getwd()   

 **#sets the working directory to where you want.**

 setwd("home/R/Rscripts") 


 **#fetches the pdb file from the protein data bank and saves to dataframe 'pb'**

 pb <- read.pdb("insert PDB ID")  

 **#trim to protein only**

 pb.prot <- trim.pdb(pb, "protein")

 **#calculates the torsion angles of the protein and save to dataframe 'tor'**

 tor <- torsion.pdb(pb.prot) 

 **#to get the number of rows and columns of 'tor'**

 dim(tor$tbl) 

 **#identify each row by their chain, residue ID and residue Number obtained from your PDB entry**

 res_label <- paste(pb.prot$atom$chain[pb.prot$calpha], pb.prot$atom$resid[pb.prot$calpha], pb.prot$atom$resno[pb.prot$calpha], sep="-") 


 rownames(tor$tbl) <- res_label

 **#creates a table of the torsion angle**

 torsion <- tor$tbl  

 #For example, to look at the angles for AA, residue X from chain A

 tor$tbl["A-GLY-65",]

 **#convert "double" into a datatype**

 dataframe_df=as.data.frame.matrix(torsion)

 **#write dataframe to a .csv file**

 write.csv(dataframe_df, file="name.csv", row.names=TRUE,col.names=TRUE)
```